# Initramfs - Set hostname from custom initrd script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, automation, initramfs

In our company, I'm creating an Ubuntu Autoinstaller (v. 20.04). For some company reasons, its required modify initramfs. (initrd file).

I'm created a script, and added a link to `init` file in `main` initrd folder. Its showing correctly, but I did not find a solution, how from this script, set hostname for currently installed system. Hostname after autoinstallation is `ubuntu` always.

Question is: How to set hostname from custom initrd script?

I'm tried a lot attempts, but neither works.:

```
netcfg/get_hostname=$hostnam
```

or

```
mdadm --assemble --scan --homehost='$hostnam' --auto=yes --auto-update-homehost
```

or

```
echo "export HOST=\"$hostnam\"" | tee -a /etc/casper.conf >/dev/null
```

or

```
echo $hostnam | tee /etc/hostname >/dev/null
```

or

```
hostnamectl set-hostname $hostnam
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the initramfs instead of any of the normal ways?

Answer (score 1):

Answering the question in the title (I came here searching for this):

The hostname for the currently running kernel (or namespace) can be set via:

```bash
echo "machine1" > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
```

assuming you want your hostname to be `machine1`.
This also works in the initrd (where tools like `hostname` are not available).

The original question seems to ask about modifying the installation procedure, though.
For debian and older ubuntu versions, preseed was the correct way of setting the hostname.
You would need to provide

```
netcfg/get_hostname=machine1
```

as a kernel command line argument (from the bootloader), and also set it in preseed.cfg.

Newer Ubuntu versions (20.04 and later) have a completely different installer
that uses cloud-init to set things like hostname:
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-quickstart

There, you need to serve (via http(s)) a user-data YAML file that can set the hostname:

```yaml
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: machine1
# (...)
```

and you boot the installer kernel with arguments:

```
autoinstall ds=nocloud-net;s=http://webserver/
```

where `webserver` is the machine that hosts the user-data file.